# How can I generate a 501 error?

Tags: http, error-handling, http-headers

What exactly are the reason(s) a 501 error is caused, and is there a way to do reproduce it on my site? I need to reproduce so that I can see how the system throws the error, and so that I can make sure the error page looks correct.

Comment: I'm not positive if this is the appropriate forum for this question - please let me know if I should post it on another StackExhange site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can telnet to the server and give it a method it doesn't understand, like this:

```
$ telnet myserver 80
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to myserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
NOTVALID / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Allow: POST,OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,TRACE
Content-Length: 196
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Not Implemented</title>
...
```

The piece of that HTTP conversation that you type is `NOTVALID / HTTP/1.0 <enter> <enter>`.

Comment: The only thing is - I need to see the error thrown on the front end, in a browser.

Comment: @jbyrd: Then copy/paste the response (the `<!DOCTYPE...` bit) into a file, and load that file into your browser.

Comment: Yes.  I see what you're getting at - you want to know how the browser will react when the server throws a 501.  But I don't know how that could happen - how could the browser send the server a method it doesn't understand?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was wondering. I didn't know if this could be done by sending something through the header, or some other way.

Comment: @jbyrd: Look on the bright side -  if it's not possible to make it happen, there's no need to test it. :-)